# In botframework how to modify sent message to teams channel once user replied

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to modify the last message sent by Bot to user once the user responds.

For that I am trying to use the rest api which expects the conversation id and activity id.

The problem I face is that this api works only when the activityId is the replyToId of the sent message. But the replyToId is not available at the time of sending message or even during the send middleware. It gets generated inside the Connector postMessage function which is not available to the middleware to store.

How can I get a valid activityId to modify the message that is sent from Bot by the Bot? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In V3

```
session.sendBartch( (e, addresses) =>{
  // addresses contain the id that now can be used for modifying

})
```

In V4

```
responses = await context.sendActivities( [ activities array]) 
// responses contain the id required for modifying.
```